# How to create an object with data in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java-8

I am writing a function that will create an object with data.  So far I get objects with data but individually not as a collection.  I would like to return an object with all designated data as one Student object, not just one input for every object. I tried to add objList.add(obj) out of the for loop too and outputs all null.
Here is the code

```
class Student{  
   int id;     
   String name;    
   int age;         
public Student(int id, String name, int age) {  
        this.id = id;    
        this.name = name;         
        this.age = age;     
   } 
} 

public static List<Object> createObject(Student st, List<Map<String, String>> csvStudentData) {
    List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<>();
    Object obj = null;

    for(Map<String, String> studentData: csvStudentData) { 
       for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry = studentData.entrySet())  {
           String key = entry.getKey();
           String val = entry.getValue();
           obj = insertObjectData(st.getClass(), key, value);
           objList.add(obj);
       }
    }
    return objList;
}
```

Comment: What does your insertObjectData method do? Can you post that too?

Comment: `List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<>();` should this not be a `List` of `Students` ?

Comment: It will be difficult to answer unless you explain what *insertObjectData* does. An example will also help

Comment: It’s a questionable design to have a `Student` parameter whose only purpose is to call `getClass()` on it. To get a reference to the `Class` object representing `Student`, you can just use `Student.class`. Further, don’t declare the `obj` variable outside the loop when it has no meaning there. Declare it right where you initialize it with `insertObjectData(st.getClass(), key, value)`. Or omit it and pass `insertObjectData(st.getClass(), key, value)` directly to `objList.add(…);`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it in java-8 stream

```
 List<Object> objList = csvStudentData.stream() 
              .flatMap(map->map.entrySet()
                               .stream()
                               .map(entry->insertObjectData(st.getClass(), entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `List<Object>` - suggest that something is wrong with his design.

Comment: yes i agree @ScaryWombat, but i just showed him the translating current approach using java-8

Comment: Additionally, the question doesn't seek for a solution with a stream or java-8 either.. if the code for `insertObjectData` doesn't work as stated in the question, it wouldn't work for the code here in the answer either.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It was, but the tag stands inappropriate as per the details of the question.

Comment: The insertObjectData does work and puts its data with the field that matches with the key in that for loop map entry.  Thank you @Deadpool and ScaryWombat, I will try those approaches!

Comment: But no more now after the edit. I'm okay in helpling OP figuring about the problem, since it was tagged as java-8 i thought he is looking for java-8 solution

Comment: @Deadpool what did you modify? In your feedback? Its nice to use stream with Java 8 ...

Comment: @Deadpool The tag for Java-8 is not appropriate at least unless the OP modifies the question to another problem altogether. For one, the question currently as it stands and the answer(this) that has been marked there is no way it could help a future reader. Do you think the solution you've provided in any manner answers the question stated? (Downvoted both, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

You modify the method's body by the following:

```
public static List<Object> createObject(Student st, List<Map<String, String>> csvStudentData) {
    List<Student> objList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map<String, String> studentData: csvStudentData) { 
       Student student = new Student();
       for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry = studentData.entrySet())  {
           String key = entry.getKey();
           String val = entry.getValue();
           Field  field = Student.class.getDeclaredField(key);
           student.set(field, value);
       }
        objList.add(student);
    }
    return objList;
}
```

you also add a default constructor in the class `Student`